# ui-router multiple views inside a sub view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have the following structure in my angular application template structure:

partials/main.html

```
<body ui-view></body>
```

partials/club.html

```
<main role="main" ui-view></main>
<div class="modal" ui-view="modal"></div>
```

partials/club.members.html

```
<div class="md-view">
    <div class="master-view">...</div>
    <div class="detail-view" ui-view></div>
</div>
```

partials/club.members.view.html

```
<div class="card">...</div>
```

partials/club.members.assign.html

```
<span class="member_name" ng-bind="memberName"></span>
```

app.js:

```
$stateProvider.state('club', {
   url: '/:club_id',
   templateUrl: '/partials/club.html',
   controller: 'ClubViewCtrl'
}).state('club.members', {
   url: '/members',
   templateUrl: '/partials/club.members.html',
   controller: 'MemberListCtrl'
}).state('club.members.view', {
   url: '/:member_id',
   templateUrl: '/partials/club.members.html',
   controller: 'MemberViewCtrl' 
}).state('club.members.view.assign', {
   url: '/assign',
   views: {
      'modal': {
         templateUrl: '/partials/club.members.assign.html',
         controller: 'MemberAssignCtrl'
       }
   }
});
```

Currently, everything works till club.members.view:

```
/my-club/members/1
```

However, when I got to club.members.view.assign:

```
/my-club/members/1/assign
```

For some reason this doesn't even call anything inside MemberAssignCtrl. Can someone shed a light on this issue for me?

Comment: I'm guessing those missing quotes on `templateUrl` are a copy-paste error, right?

Comment: yeah oops..... I forgot fixed it now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are referencing a view which is not in the same namespace as your current view, you will have to use absolute names.

In your case change

```
views: {
   'modal': {
      templateUrl: '/partials/club.members.assign.html',
      controller: 'MemberAssignCtrl'
    }
}
```

To:

```
views: {
   'modal@club': {
      templateUrl: '/partials/club.members.assign.html',
      controller: 'MemberAssignCtrl'
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this mean that the view is absolute to the club state?

Comment: For reference I get all this from: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views

Comment: It means the view is located in the club state and you can't reference it relatively from the club.members.view.assign state and thus need to reference it with an absolute (and globally unique) identifier.